# If $\mathbb P(X=1)=p$ and $\mathbb P(X=-1)=1-p$ what is the law of $X$?

Tags: probability

Let $p\in (0,1)$. If $\mathbb P(X=1)=p$ and $\mathbb P(X=-1)=1-p$ what is the law of $X$ ? It looks to be a Bernoulli, in the sense that there are two possibility, namely $1$ and $-1-$, However, in a Bernoulli law, the expectation should be $p$, whereas here, the expectation if $2p-1$. Is there a name for such law ?

Comment: In the special case of $p = 1/2$, this is called a Rademacher distribution. I don't think it has a specific name for the general case.

Comment: You have the complete Probability Mass Function (PMF) for $X$ so you have everything needed to calculate probabilities that concern $X$. I do not know what you mean when you say the "law of $X$" so your question could be clarified to state what that means. I suspect that when you define "law of $X$" you will have gone most of the way to answering your own question. Note that $X \in \{-1,1\}$ while a Bernoulli takes values in the set $\{0,1\}$.

Answer (score 1):

You can say that the linear transformation can be applied, if you start with the bernoulli distributed variable  as $Y\sim\textrm{Ber}(p)$. So $X=a\cdot Y+b$. We need to find the the parameters $a$ and $b$. For this purpose we use the value pairs $(Y/X)$, which are  $(0/-1)$, $(1/1)$ to set up two equations.

$-1=a\cdot 0+b \qquad\Rightarrow b=-1$

$1=a+b  \qquad \qquad \Rightarrow a=-b+1\Rightarrow a=2$

So $X=2Y-1$. We know that $\mathbb E(Y)=p$ and $Var(Y)=p\cdot (1-p)$. Then the expected value of $X$ is $\mathbb E(2Y-1)=2\cdot \mathbb E(Y)-1=2p-1$. And the variance of $X$ is $Var(2Y-1)=4\cdot Var(Y)=4\cdot p\cdot (1-p)$.